kendo-grid-checkbox-column in grid angular 17
i want multiple checkbox in grid (kendo UI)
I have common grid
This is my code from common-grid component.
look like that 

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


i want checkbox button for both place use can select all using top checkbox look like 

[![enter image description here][2]][2] 


Please let me know if someone know the ans

  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/1rbM423L.png
  [2]: https://i.sstatic.net/wifxiIfY.png


my common-Grid code export class ColumnSetting {
field: string;
displayField?: string;
title: string;
format?: string;
width?: number = 100;
type: ColumnTypeEnum;
filterType?: 'text' | 'numeric' | 'boolean' | 'date';
defaultValue?: any = null;
validators?: ValidatorFn[];
validatorMessage?: string;
onValueChangeFunc?: (formGroup: UntypedFormGroup) => void;
isCheckbox?: boolean = false;
}

i want to active checkbox here  this.columns = [
{
field: '',
title: '',
type: ColumnTypeEnum.Checkbox,
width : 40
  },
  {
    field: 'userId',
    title: 'UserID',
    type: ColumnTypeEnum.Hidden,
    defaultValue: 0
  }

